# Where to put exclamation mark when methods are chained

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following array and methods:

```
array = ["1", 0, "a", ""]
array.reject(&:blank?).map(&:to_i).reject{|i| i == 0}
```

If I'd like to save changes in place utilizing the exclamation mark, e.g. `.map!(&:to_i)`, should the mark be placed after every method or otherwise - where?

Comment: The explanation mark is not a modifier of a method's behaviour, it's part of the method name.

Comment: How does this change my question?

Comment: "at the same place"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclamation marks are not modifiers.

```
array.reject!(&:blank?).map!(&:to_i).reject!{|i| i == 0}
```

However, this code is subtly wrong. From [`reject!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) docs:

> returns nil if no changes were made.

Whoops! This could break your whole chain. Instead, you're supposed to use [delete_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if), which always returns the array.

```
array.delete_if(&:blank?).map!(&:to_i).delete_if{|i| i == 0}
```

---

Yes, it's confusing it doesn't have a bang, but it does modify in-place. From the docs:

> The array is changed instantly every time the block is called, not after the iteration is over.

Comment: The bang is not necessarily added on methods which change their receiver but generally on methods wich do something potentially dangerous. Each time there exists a bang method, there should also be a non-bang method which should be safer. That said, this is one of the conventions which is less then fully accepted.

Comment: I'd argue that, since `delete_if` is just `reject!` that returns the array (literally in the MRI source), it should have a bang :).

Comment: @Ven, readers may incorrectly infer for your comment that `delete_if` and `reject!` are equivalent. As you know, when no changes are made, `delete_if` returns the array whereas `reject!` returns `nil`. There are of course many methods that modify the receiver that do not have a bang. Should we write `arr <<! 3`?